Azure Deleting a function
I am trying to delete a function app so that I can recreate it but when I try to recreate it says it already exists
This is the command I used to delete app
az functionapp delete --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group azure-functions

Then I listed the fucntions list and it returned nothing since I have no other functions.
az functionapp list --output table

I even went as far as to delete the resource group where function resides. The resource group is gone
az group delete --name azure-functions

Yet when I try to run this code I get an error
az functionapp create --resource-group azure-functions2 --consumption-plan-location eastus --runtime python --runtime-version 3.11 --functions-version 4 --name MyFunctionApp --storage-account azurefunctions --os-type Linux

Error output
Website with given name MyFunctionApp already exists.

I can probably create one with a new name yes but I rather make sure I have cleaned house and I dont have any old loose ends that may cause confusion when I redeploy.
Is there some thing I am missing to delete somewhere. I deleted the resource that had the function I am at a loss here. I do have 1 more resource group but that has 0 functions.

the az functionapp delete  command doesnt instantly delete.  It schedules a background delete and hides the function from view. this is why it doesn't appear in az functionapp list 
try waiting 15 mins before creating the function again.
I tend to use the portal for function delete as it gives a notification when the job is actually done.
also the delete command doesn't remove the storage account depending on your setup you may need to delete that too.

Thank you Twisted. Yes I have tried few more times I deleted over the weekend. I used Vscode and portal to delete everything related to this funciton even the resource group.

Azure Function Apps have a global scope. A function app is stored globally despite of region or location  in domain as <name>.azurewebsites.net. So, when you have deleted a function app, then someone might have created with that name due to which you are unable to  create and you will get an error saying:
az functionapp create --resource-group rg --consumption-plan-location westus --runtime python --runtime-version 3.11 --functions-version 4 --name rtest --storage-account testst76 --os-type Linux



I even went as far as to delete the resource group where function resides. The resource group is gone

Yes, you might have deleted but someone might have used it and created it.
According to SO-Thread1 and SO-Thread2 it says:

Function Apps or and PaaS services with public endpoints must have globally unique name

Even while creating it in Portal when i use common name demo98 it says not available  and use some other unique name, it takes it:


Thank you for the response RithwikBojja. Your statement make sense to me and I agree 100%. But I dropped and created the function is a span of 2 mins. originally its been 2 days now. Also the name I had was very long and not a common name so although yes possible highly unlikely someone else got name in a span of 2 minutes. I still believe that I have left something registered somewhere and it thinks its in use.

AFAIK, there will be thousand's of apps that will be created at a single moment, So, this is the only reason I feel you are getting that error and there is no soft delete option for function apps as keyvaults, so no option to not to be deleted.

RithwikBojja your right there are 1000s of apps created  but the odds of same app name done by someone else at the same time as me is highly unlikely within a span of 2 mins?
Original app name "NFLWeatherFunctionApp" This seems to be long and very specific

You are right that it is unique, but a function app with that name exists which might have created in 2min of your deletion, and I don't see any other reason why you get that error.
